# I wish to do pickled onions but am unable to get Brown vinegar only Apple Cider Vinegar

Tags: pickles

I am unable to get Brown vinegar, so is it ok to use Apple Cider Vinegar

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "brown vinegar"?  That term has different meanings in different countries.

Comment: Apple cider vinegar is consider 'brown,' as are malt, balsamic and brown rice. And, yes, it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any type of vinegar works.

update:
Responding to comment below, I guess I would stay away from distilled white vinegar and and any "heavy" types such as balsamico, jejiang, shanxi and so on. Apple cider vinegar, white or red wine vinegar, sherry vinegar and so on would all work well.

Comment: Uh... what is considered "any type" is very regional :) I am sure 25% distilled vinegar, or a strong chinkiang, will make interesting but inexpected styles of pickled onion :)

Comment: That's very true! I suppose even synthesised acetic acid would work but not make anything enticing.